PHP8 PHP-FPM how to exclude function args on www-error.log
I had: /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
and php.ini already log Fatal errors.
All Fatal errors logs have function args. Example:
myFunction('hello','bla blabla')
And these args show on the www-error.log, I research many options on php.ini but I don't see any option for only log error trace, but ignore / exclude the args ( hello, ' blablabl ')
If you know any of this, please help.

Using a custom error handler to control the log message I think would be feasible, check the comments regarding 'fatal' errors, as they need to be handled slightly differently https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php
